# Web база данных. Как создать?

Tags: sql, indexeddb, websqldatabase

Я хочу из базы данных сервера передать в формате json часть данных и затем записать их в базу данных браузера. Я читал, есть IndexedDB и Веб-база данных SQL. Какую выбрать? 
Подскажите пожалуйста примеры- как это сделать с самого начало до рабочего состояния, а то что-то нахожу лишь фрагменты кода.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Описание здесь http://www.onlywebpro.com/2012/12/23/html5-storage-indexeddb/

Пример кода

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>IndexedDb Demo | onlyWebPro.com</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//prefixes of implementation that we want to test
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

//prefixes of window.IDB objects
window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange

if (!window.indexedDB) {
    window.alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB.")
}

const customerData = [
  { id: "00-01", name: "Bill", age: 35, email: "bill@company.com" },
  { id: "00-02", name: "Donna", age: 32, email: "donna@home.org" }
];


var db;
var request = window.indexedDB.open("newDatabase", 1);

request.onerror = function(event) {
  console.log("error: ");
};

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  db = request.result;
  console.log("success: "+ db);
};

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        var db = event.target.result;
        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("customers", {keyPath: "id"});
        for (var i in customerData) {
                objectStore.add(customerData[i]);      
        }
}

function read() {
        var transaction = db.transaction(["customers"]);
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("customers");
        var request = objectStore.get("00-03");
        request.onerror = function(event) {
          alert("Unable to retrieve daa from database!");
        };
        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
          // Do something with the request.result!
          if(request.result) {
                alert("Name: " + request.result.name + ", Age: " + request.result.age + ", Email: " + request.result.email);
          } else {
                alert("Kenny couldn't be found in your database!"); 
          }
        };
}

function readAll() {
        var objectStore = db.transaction("customers").objectStore("customers");

        objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
          var cursor = event.target.result;
          if (cursor) {
                alert("Name for id " + cursor.key + " is " + cursor.value.name + ", Age: " + cursor.value.age + ", Email: " + cursor.value.email);
                cursor.continue();
          }
          else {
                alert("No more entries!");
          }
        };     
}

function add() {
        var request = db.transaction(["customers"], "readwrite")
                .objectStore("customers")
                .add({ id: "00-03", name: "Kenny", age: 19, email: "kenny@planet.org" });

        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
                alert("Kenny has been added to your database.");
        };

        request.onerror = function(event) {
                alert("Unable to add data\r\nKenny is aready exist in your database! ");       
        }

}

function remove() {

        var request = db.transaction(["customers"], "readwrite")
                .objectStore("customers")
                .delete("00-03");
        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
          alert("Kenny's entry has been removed from your database.");
        };
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="read()">Read single data from indexedDb</button>
<button onclick="readAll()">Read all data from indexedDb</button>
<button onclick="add()">Add data to indexedDb</button>
<button onclick="remove()">Delete data from indexedDb</button>
</body>
</html>
```